# Bolding/underlining/strikethrough-ing text in mutt

Tags: email, mutt

Is there any way to **bold**, <strike>strike</strike>, or underline text in mutt?

For instance, I currently have a couple of lines in my muttrc to make URLs and email addresses blue text on white background:

> `color body blue white` *regex*

but I'd rather have that be blueunderline on white background. Likewise, I'd like to be able to bold unread mails in the index.

(dunno if it's relevant, but I'm using Ubuntu's mutt-patched, which is compiled with ncurses.)

Comment: Just a warning: I just found out this week that strikethrough text from my Mac's Mail does not appear as strikethrough on Windows...

Answer (score 3):

You can get bold colors in **xterm** by prefixing them with "bright".  So in your case:

```
color body brightblue white regex
```

would make the blue text appear bold.

Other terminals however (**eterm**, **konsole**, **gnome-terminal**) tend to actually make the text brighter instead of bold.  I don't know any solution for those terminals.

Answer (score -1):

You can do bold and underline but not strike through.

Replace "body" in

```
color body blue white regex
```

with "bold" and "underline" respectively.

Comment: "body" here is the color group that Steve wants to change.  In that field, "bold" and "underline" are the color groups for when mutt highlights bold and underline text in HTML content.